# Unity2D Vector2 does not work

Tags: c#, position, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a Crossy Road clone in Unity 2D and I get an error on line 34.
I'm not sure what I have missed but I need another perspective. 
To be specific I'm getting an error on this statement:

```
if (transform.position != new Vector2(curPosition.x, transform.position.y) + nextDir)
```

and everything is marked red.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 nextDir;
    public float jumpForce = 100;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float speedRot = 100;
    public float rotationOffset;
    Rigidbody rb;
    public Vector2 curPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        curPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position != new Vector2(curPosition.x, transform.position.y) + nextDir)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector2(curPosition.x, transform.position.y) + nextDir, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            nextDir = Vector2.zero;
            curPosition = transform.position;
            curPosition.x = Mathf.Round(curPosition.x);
            curPosition.y = Mathf.Round(curPosition.y);
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
            {
                nextDir.x = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
                Move();
            }
            else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0)
            {
                nextDir.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
                Move();
            }
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy and paste what error you're getting.

Comment: @m.rogalski There is no "rigidbody" attached to the "Character" object

Comment: Add this `[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]` at the top of your class. like such : `[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))] public class ...`

Comment: @m.rogalski Now im getting an error saying : Operator '!=' is to ambigous on operands of type vector 2 and 3

Comment: And that's the error you should have. You're trying to compare `Vector2` to `Vector3` which is not what you want

Comment: @m.rogalski where am i doing that?

Answer (score 0):

First error ( about lack of `Rigidbody2D` component ) can be solved by adding `RequireComponent` attribute on top of the `PlayerController` :

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D)]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // rest of your code
```

And the you're trying to compare object with 3 axis to the one with 2 axis

```
    void Update()
    {
        // here you're trying to compare Vector3 ( transform.position )
        // to Vector2, (3 axis with 2 axis)
        //if (transform.position != new Vector2(curPosition.x, transform.position.y) + nextDir)
        // change it to this 
        Vector2 cmp = new Vector2(curPosition.x, transform.position.y) + nextDir;
        if(cmp[0] != transform.position[0] || cmp[1] != transform.position[1])
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector2(curPosition.x, transform.position.y) + nextDir, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        // rest of the update's body
    }

    // rest of your code ...
}
```